# Determining convergence of $\frac{n}{e^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to determine if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n}$ is converging

This is what I have so far

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n}$ converges by the geometric series test since $\frac{1}{e}$ < 1

This seems too simple of answer and was wondering if this was even a geometric sequence.

Comment: No, this is not a geometric series.

Comment: That's what I figured, would using the integral test be the correct method?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, it was fixed.

Comment: Yes. The integral test will work nicely.

Comment: Thank you, corrected the OP as well

Comment: I believe the ratio test will work as well due to the fact you listed: $1/e < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several standard tests that work equally well.  Here, let's apply the root test.  Proceeding, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n}{e^n}}=e^{-1}$$

Thus, the series converges.

We can, in fact, evaluate the series.  Let the function $f(x)$ be given by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.  Then, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.  We can differentiate the power series term-by-term to find

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $x$ reveals

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

whence setting $x=1/e$ yields the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{e^n}=\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}}$$